# codeigniter image update

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm stuck on a problem with image uploader. I've created the image uploader which works fine but I also need to edit them. 
When I add a need image the db column updates correctly but I if don't change the image and leave it as it is, I get an error *"Column 'image' cannot be null"*

This is the code for the update section:

```
else if ($type == 'update')
{

    if($this->input->post('image')) {
        $fdata = $this->savenew();
        $data['image'] = $fdata['upload_data']['file_name'];

    } else {
         $data['image'] = $this->input->post('current_image');


    }

    $return = $this->add_radio_model->update($id, $data);
}
```

Sorry if I wasn't very explicit

EDIT:

```
     private function savenew(){                

     $config['upload_path'] = './assets/'; //Make SURE that you chmod this directory to 777!
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
     $config['max_size']    = '0'; // 0 = no limit on file size (this also depends on your PHP configuration)
     $config['remove_spaces']=TRUE; //Remove spaces from the file name

     $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
    {
            $data['error']= array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            log_message('error',$data['error']);
            }
            else
                {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                }
        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: what you get in `echo var_dump($this->input->post('current_image'))` ?

Comment: @GBD if I use it in  if($this->input->post('image')) { } I get the value from db but if I use it in else {} I don't get enything

Comment: Can you echo "hello" in else part ? see it execute or not when there is no image file

Comment: it means .it always going into if part. do in if part: `$data['image'] = !empty($fdata['upload_data']['file_name'])?$fdata['upload_data']['file_name']:$this->input->post('current_image');`

Comment: what you get if echo $data['image'] ?

Comment: It's working now(forgot about $fdata = $this->savenew();). Now if I don't add a image i get a php notice "Message:  Array to string conversion"

Comment: Ok. then paste result of var_dump($this->input->post('current_image')) ?

Comment: string(10) "156660.jpg" in if. In else I got nothing

Comment: ahh.. i think.. can you paste your modified code ?

Comment: else if ($type == 'update')
    {
  
        if($this->input->post('image')) {
           $fdata = $this->savenew();
   $data['image'] = !empty($fdata['upload_data']['file_name'])?$fdata['upload_data']['file_name']:$this->input->post('current_image');
   
        } else {
             $data['image'] = $this->input->post('current_image');
   
   
        }
       
  $return = $this->add_radio_model->update($id, $data);
    }

Comment: are you able to echo "hello" into else part ? when you not add image

Comment: I can't because it says that I don't have enough reputation.
I echo hello in else but no result.

Comment: which means not going into else part. ok now echo "hello" in if part when you not add image

Comment: I've done that and the echo it's working in if

Comment: it means in both case when you add image or not add image, it going in if part only. can you paste code of $this->savenew() function into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per our comments thread, here you need to change your code

```
else if ($type == 'update')
{
    if($this->input->post('image')) {
        $fdata = $this->savenew();
        // first always set current image  
        $data['image'] = $this->input->post('current_image');
        // second check if new image added if yes, then update otherwise keep original image as it is
        if(isset($fdata['upload_data'])){
           $data['image'] = $fdata['upload_data']['file_name'];
        }
    }
    $return = $this->add_radio_model->update($id, $data);
}
```

For second problem: `A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Array to string conversion Filename: libraries/Log.php Line Number: 99`

Change:

```
$data['error']= array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
log_message('error',$data['error']);
```

TO

```
log_message('error',(string) $this->upload->display_errors());
```

Comment: Same php notice when I don't insert any image. `A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: libraries/Log.php

Line Number: 99`

Comment: I think this problem is in Log.php

Comment: in Log.php on line 99 I have `$message .= $level.' '.(($level == 'INFO') ? ' -' : '-').' '.date($this->_date_fmt). ' --> '.$msg."\n";`

Comment: new error:). `Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: controllers/add.php

Line Number: 257` line 257 is `return $data;`

Comment: Put this $data = array(); before `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))`