# CodeIgniter - Image on database is gone when trying to not update the image

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

First at all I'm sorry for my bad English, I have been searching all how to fix my problem (Image on database is gone when trying to not update the image) and I found this : [codeigniter image update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218842/codeigniter-image-update)

My problem is pretty same like that question, but when I try to fix it to be like that its still error.

So I can update an image or change the old image into new image, but when I try to not update the image (maybe just edit the another values in form, not the image), the image value on database is gone (NULL). And what I want is when I not update the image, the image is still same like the old image. Here is my code, placed in same file on model directory :

**Constructor :**

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // Setting up the upload configuration
    $config['upload_path']      = 'photo_dir/';
    $config['allowed_types']    = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['file_ext_tolower'] = TRUE;
    $config['max_size']         = 2048;
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
}
```

**Function to get old image value :**

```
// This function is to read the old image in database
private function _selected_img($id)
{
    return $this->db->select()
                    ->from('tb_exam')
                    ->where('id_exam', $id)
                    ->limit(1)
                    ->get()
                    ->row();
}
```

**Update function :**

```
// The update function
public function update($id)
{
    // Get the old image first and declare it in variable `file`
    $file = $this->_selected_img($id)->img;

    // Upload the image
    $this->upload->do_upload('img');

    // If upload image data is not null, and then change the
    // `file` value into the image file_name
    if ($this->upload->data() !== '')
    {
        $file = $this->upload->data('file_name');
    }

    // Object to update
    $this->object = array(
        'id_teacher'        => $this->input->post('id_teacher'),
        'id_subject'        => $this->input->post('id_subject'),
        'question'          => $this->input->post('question'),
        'img'               => $file,
        'option_a'          => $this->input->post('option_a'),
        'option_b'          => $this->input->post('option_b'),
        'option_c'          => $this->input->post('option_c'),
        'option_d'          => $this->input->post('option_d'),
        'option_e'          => $this->input->post('option_e'),
        'answer_key'        => $this->input->post('answer_key')
    );

    // Update the data
    $this->db->where($this->main_id, $id)->update($this->table, $this->object);

    // If record is success, return TRUE
    // but if not, return FALSE
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

All of your helps and answer is highly appreciated !

Comment: It's clear that when running an update that your image `$file` variable is empty. Add a check to see if there is any changes and then only update those changes.

Comment: @Bankzilla what do you mean that `$file` is empty? I was declare first on my "update function" (`public function update($id)`) in line 5

Comment: I did not see the private function for `_selected_img`. Why are you updating the image file every time even if the user never changed it?

Comment: @Bankzilla I was wrote on top, bottom of constructor. So the user have 2 options, user change the image as well as another values, or the user only change the another values. What I want is when user only change the values except the image, the image is not changed. But in this case the image value is suddenly gone. I was try everything but I can't fix this

Comment: Do a dump of `$this->upload->data()` after updating the field (when you haven't changed the image), you'll probably notice that this is not actually null and thus it's running and changing your `$file` variable

Comment: @Bankzilla what should I do to do a dump in that upload data?

Comment: Before the if condition do `var_dump($this->upload->data());`

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the old image name correctly. please check that by `echo $file; exit;`
if you are not getting the file name correctly use the following code to get the old image name`$query = $this->db->get_where('tb_exam', array('id_exam' => $id));
$data=$query->result_array();
$file=$data[0]['img'];`

use this code directly in your update function

Comment: Have you getting $id and $file. Please check it first

Comment: Yes I was tried in code of course in SQL, both of those is works (display the name of file and ID of the data), but when I tried to put it to update the image its not working